# Ping from specific port of device

Tags: ubuntu, ping, port

AOA,
Hello,
I have a device on which Ubuntu-server is installed. I have two ports, connected to LAN and device respectively. When I ping to some IP address it listens through the port not wanted by me to listen through it, rather I want to ping the IP address through other port of the same device.
What should I do.

Comment: does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/769541/is-it-possible-to-ping-an-addressport

Comment: By "port" do you mean port like a TCP port? Or interface like `eth0`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to ping an address:port?](https://superuser.com/questions/769541/is-it-possible-to-ping-an-addressport)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally `ping` sends packets wherever the routing table tells it to. For example, if eth0 is configured for 192.168.1.x/24 and eth1 is configured for 192.168.7.x/24, and you're trying to reach 192.168.7.y, the routing table alone should be enough to ensure that it goes through eth1.

So if that's not happening, you might want to use `ip route add` to define the correct routes and gateways (after making sure you have the correct *address* configuration).

In some cases, you can use ping's `-I` option (as in `ping -I eth0`) to force packets to be sent through a specific interface. Note that this works *only* for directly-connected devices (i.e. only for addresses which are in your local subnet), as it completely bypasses any gateway lookup.